2 монитора 2 рабочих стола
Есть два монитора. Как можно при включении Windows, автоматически создать второй виртуальный рабочий стол для второго монитора и запустить приложение на второй рабочий стол.

https://www.actualtools.com/multiplemonitors/

А в чём проблема? Всё работает и так. Расширяешь рабочий стол на оба монитора. Полоса задач и системное меню там имеются, только трея нет. Между мониторами окна перемещаются мышкой или Win+Shist+(LeftArrow / Right Arrow). Последнее положение окна приложения запоминается.

В Windows 11 это решено естественным, понятным и стабильным способом.

@FoxFox А в десятке что?

@rotabor, По-моему, Вопрос был не просто про расширение экрана на два монитора, а про использование виртуальных рабочих столов. Пользователь хочет автоматически создавать второй виртуальный рабочий стол при запуске системы и запускать на нем приложение, которое будет выводиться на второй физический монитор

да, виртуальный рабочий стол. Включили компьютер и у нас сразу два виртуальных рабочих стола на каждый монитор.

Windows не имеет встроенной функции для автоматического создания второго рабочего стола при загрузке. Но можно использовать сторонние утилиты и скрипты для автоматизации этого процесса...есть способ через AutoHotkey со скриптами, а есть, что я выше предложила программу-она что то вроде 25 долларов стоит, поэтому лучше подождать ответ со скриптами(но есть пробный месяц)

Видел также решение на AutoHotkey. А можно это сделать на powershall?

Видел такой вариант https://github.com/MScholtes/PSVirtualDesktop
